# Is it ok to ask about scholars who explore Muhammad's reasoning concerning the Satanic Verses?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'm trying to understand Muhammad's reasons for delivering the Satanic Verses, and his reasons for later abrogating them. From the numerous biographies I've read, I conclude that he was a political genius; the placement of the Black Stone, getting the Ansar to accept the Muhajirun, etc. He knew how to get people to compromise. The Satanic Verses seem an uncharacteristic blunder. I'm wondering whether anyone has explored the issue without involving Shaytan and Jibril, considering only Muhammad's thinking on the matter.

So far, my attempts at asking questions like this on SE.islam and SE.christianity have degenerated into pointless sectarian conversation. I can imagine a question about the Satanic Verses going in the same direction.

So, is it ok to ask this question, and if so, can anyone advise me on how to word it so as to discourage comments and answers that would distract from my intended question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, I'm not convinced that it's possible to completely avoid pointless sectarian conversation, no matter how well-written and clear the question is. Pointless sectarians have a habit of not needing actual reasons to bring up their opinions. The best thing you can do about that is just flag non-constructive and argumentative comments as soon as they come up rather than engage them.

That said, the biggest issue with the question is that it presumes that the incident of the Satanic Verses actually occurred; this is a matter in which there is significant dispute, especially between orientalist and Islamic scholars (whereby many of the former consider it authentic (or at least reasonably likely) while many of the latter consider the relevant narrations weak and reject them as a contradiction to the stronger-established principle of prophetic infallibility).

So for writing your question, I'd make a strong consideration of the following points:

- Islamic scholars as a whole are unlikely to reject "involving Shaytan and Jibril", especially since the narrations in this regard clearly mention them, so you're mostly looking for the perspective of secular/orientalist scholars.
- Avoid Truth claims that the incident did (or did not) happen; make it clear that you're simply looking for resources from that perspective. Lampshading that you know that there's a difference of opinion would probably be advisable.
- A new tag for secular-scholars or secular-history or something along those lines might be useful; not sure exactly what best to call it though. The site already has a tag [secular](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secular) which can be used, but skimming its use-cases (and lack of wiki) I'm not sure if that'd be helpful.
- The Flag button is your friend.

Comment: As always, thank you.